# Bamboo remote agent logging configuration on Windows

Tags: bamboo

I have a Bamboo remote agent v5.12.3 installed on a Windows 2012 Server machine. After upgrade from v5.9.7 log file contains error messages saying that access to write log file into root directory was denied.

This is fragment of log file with the exception:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 | log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 | java.io.FileNotFoundException: \atlassian-bamboo.log (Access is denied)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent.configureLog4j(RemoteAgent.java:141)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent.start(RemoteAgent.java:73)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.bootstrap.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:30)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 | log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [filelog].
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 | log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 | java.io.FileNotFoundException: \js-atlassian-bamboo.log (Access is denied)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent.configureLog4j(RemoteAgent.java:141)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent.start(RemoteAgent.java:73)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.bootstrap.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:30)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/31 11:25:04 | log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [javascript].
```

First of all, I do not understand all the log files that Bamboo remote agent creates. There exists at least these:

- atlassian-bamboo-agent.log - which I have redirected to \logs directory. This file is correctly written with bamboo agent log records, everything is fine here...
- atlassian-bamboo.log - the agent tries to write it into C:\ directory, which I of course prevent him from.
- js-atlassian-bamboo.log - the same as previous

**Can anyone explain to me, what is the difference between these log files?**

Finally I do not understand, why the agent wants to create the atlassian-bamboo and the js-atlassian-bamboo log files in the root folder of drive C. **How can I configure the agent, so that it creates these files in another folder?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

atlassian-bamboo-agent.log -> This will capture only the activity on agent

atlassian-bamboo.log -> This will capture the logs of build /deployment which this agent is taking up

You can configure the logs , Please check below link

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboocloud/logging-in-bamboo-737184373.html